# Covert link field as link field text format?

Tags: 8

I have used the link field for the button. Here, I have to change one word as Italic. I am not able to change the word as Italic in the link field.

I want to change the link field as link's title lik formatted.

How could I achieve this without using any module.

Please suggest me!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the HTML you can Rewrite the output using tokens, see more info here: [Raw Field Value in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281733/raw-field-value-in-views/281779#281779) and in this question and answer: [Add link for each column](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281395/add-link-for-each-column/281406#281406)

Then you can emphasize a word in the output to make it italic, or wrap it with some HTML element with a class and italicize it with CSS in your theme.

If you want to make the whole link text italic you can add a class to that field and style it with CSS.

If you just want to reword the link text you can use the `Rewrite results` as mentioned.